# Tab key on external keyboard for UITextView (same as UITextField)

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextview

If i add several `UITextField` on my `View`, the user on iPad with external keyboard can press `Tab` to switch to the next one.

However, if i one of the fields is `UITextView`, that actually inserts tabulation chars into the text, so the user gets inconsistent behaviour.

Is there a way to have `UITextView` behave the same as `UITextField` in regards to tab key?